# How to execute code after all Request are done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have React app, and I inject code into DOM from backend,
How should I execute this code after All Request are done? I asking about Vanilla code because it's kind of custom script injected into the DOM

I Mean API request, XHR
I trying to execute this one

```
document.querySelector('span[data-attribute="product_cat"]').textContent = document.querySelector('span[data-attribute="product_cat"]').textContent.replace('product cat', 'categories')
```

During request there is only spinner instaed of that product_cat div

I found half-answer

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let docHeight = document.querySelector('div#page');
  let MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

  let observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (mutation.type == 'attributes' || mutation.type == "childList" || mutation.type == "characterData" || mutation.type == 'subtree') {
        document.querySelector('span[data-attribute="product_cat"]').textContent = document.querySelector('span[data-attribute="product_cat"]').textContent.replace('product cat', 'categories')
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe(docHeight, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
  });
});
```

This one work pretty well on chrome, but causes firefox crash, and also not working on IE

Comment: Depends what "all requests done" means. We can't guess what that custom script does. See [mcve]

Comment: It will be helpful if you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to happen after a set of requests are finished, I would recommend using `Promise.all()`

Example:

```
promise1 = fetch('api/some.json')  // Fetch returns a `Promise`
promise2 = fetch('api/some2.json')  // Fetch returns a `Promise`

Promise.all([promise1, promise2])  // [..., ...] accepts promises
.then(function (results) {
    console.log("All promises are done!")
})
```

Comment: Would not work, this code will be injected independly, it should stick to some kind of event

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that i can put code inside App to wrap all the functions, App is ready, and there will be injected into DOM litlle script, which will do some job